# Pourquoi 'cartésien' au lieu de 'descartésien' ?

Tags: adjectifs, noms-propres

On pourrait s'attendre à ce que l'adjectif pour Descartes soit 'descartésien'. D'autres noms de famille longs sont conservés intégralement, donc ça ne peut pas être ça. Et on comprendrait plus facilement si Descartes s'écrivait en deux mots.

Comment: Si, pour Descartes, l'explication donnée par Laure est effectivement la bonne, on ne peut pas vraiment faire de règle logique sur ce sujet. En maths, on connait les opérateurs ***d'alembertiens***, les thèses de l'Aquinate sont ***thomistes*** etc.

Comment: Sans oublier les curieux *hugo**L**iens* et les œuvres de Rameau que l'on ne sait toujours pas si elles sont *ramistes*, *ramelliennes* ou *rameauviennes*

Comment: @aCOSwt Bien sûr il n'y a pas de règle générale mais ces formations obéissent quand même à une certaine logique linguiste, même si ce n'est pas la même à chaque fois.  Alembertien (de d'Alembert), et thomiste (Thomista- Saint Thomas d'Aquin) sont des constructions fréquentes (racinien,  rousseauiste, zoliste..). La consonne d'appui dans hugolien (ou hugotique, hugotesque...) a une raison phonétique, qui peut certainement se trouver ailleurs en français.

Comment: @Laure : Je suis d'accord avec toi pour dire qu'en chaque occurrence, on pourra trouver une **raison**. Mais je n'irai pas jusqu'à dire une **logique** eu égard aux pratiques des Anglosaxons qui sont beaucoup plus systématiques que nous.

Comment: Le fait que De Gaulle ait donné l'adjectif "gaulliste" me laisse penser qu'on a simplement tendance à écarter la particule...

Answer (score 14):

René Descartes (1596-1650) écrivait en français pour être compris du plus grand nombre de personnes de son pays natal (la France) mais aussi en latin comme la plupart des savants et philosophes de cette époque afin d'être compris de la communauté scientifique internationale. Il était publié en latin sous le nom de **Renatus Cartesius**. Tous les mots s’appliquant à la pensée de Descartes (cartésien, cartésianisme) sont dérivés de son nom latin.

Sa [notice sur le site de la BNF](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/11899775/rene_descartes/) indique que parfois son nom français était orthographié en deux mots.

> Autres formes du nom : René Des Cartes (1596-1650)
> Renatus Des Cartes (1596-1650) (latin)
> Renatus Cartesius (1596-1650) (latin)